# Excel: Select the cell to the left that is greater than/less than some value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a data entry form that is used to input data from image analysis.  I take segments of images of membranes in ImageJ which I then paste the intensity values into an Excel spreadsheet.  A graph is then generated that plots the pixels from the start of the segmentation with the intensity of that pixel.  The idea is to find two peaks in the graph to find specific areas of the membrane to compare to get a value called Kp (partitioning coefficient).

See the figure below.  (b) shows how the images will look in really good pictures.  The line shows how the image can be segmented and the intensity values along those pixels in the line are copied to the Excel sheet. (c) shows a typical intensity plot with the two peaks that correspond to the membrane edges.

The original data entry page has those peaks discovered in the spreadsheet by finding the Max values in a certain area of the Excel column.  This method only works when the object in the image is a certain size.

I think there is a better algorithm to discover these peaks.  As can be seen in the Figure b, there is an extreme slope change on those peaks as compared to the rest of the graph.  My thought is to have a column next to the pixels (x) and intensity (y) columns to calculate the slope from each point.  Finding the max and minimum slope +/- some value I will be able to discover the area of the slope that corresponds to the membrane edge I am interested in.

Currently I have three columns:

```
px     intensity     slope
 0        139         
 1        138        -0.57
...
```

I want to be able to select the specific cell in the intensity column when the cell to the right contains the maximum or minimum value in that slope column.

How can I correctly implement this in Excel?

[image]

Upon implementing some of the suggestions I found a slight error to my algorithm that I was not expecting.  Sometimes the intensity plots have a more gradual change for when the membrane ends and the background image starts.  This leads to the following intensity plot as shown below.  I think an extra step that will ignore minimum slopes that are within a certain distance from maximum slope will solve this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run an index-match on this.

If intensity is in column B and slope is in column C, your formula could be -

`=INDEX(B1:C10,MATCH(MAX(C1:C10),C1:C10,0),1)` to find the intensity for the largest slope and

`=INDEX(B1:C10,MATCH(MIN(C1:C10),C1:C10,0),1)` to find the intensity for the smallest slope

Comment: please see my addition to my question.  I would like to add that the max and minimum should not be more than a certain distance from each other, say 10 rows as an example.

Comment: You can change the range of the function to specific ranges. If you don't know the local start and stop, this won't work.

Comment: I counted the number of observations and then divided that by two and used that value as an offset to indirectly access a range of the columns.

Comment: @Kevin smart, glad it helped

Answer (score 1):

You can adapt http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/961-excel-identify-cell-address.html to your purposes

basically, you use `MAX()` or `MIN()` to get the max or min values of the range, then `INDEX()` to find the cell matching that value, and `CELL("address",)` to output this as text

Comment: this worked well, but I still have some issues that you may be able to solve. How would I implement another step to have the maximum and minimum slopes should be more than 10 rows away from each other.  I will add this to the original question.